# How to convert date in flutter without using third party package?

Tags: flutter, date, dart, flutter-layout

I want to convert `Date` in Flutter without using third party package like `intl`. At the moment I'm using `DateTime.now()` to get the current date. I know about some packages but can I format date without using any third party package??

**Default Date Format**: 2021-07-22 13:45:50.200266

**Required Date Format**: 22/07/2021 (DD/MM/YYYY)

```dart
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need one hard-coded format, you can... well, hard-code it:

```dart
final date = DateTime.now();
print('${date.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${date.year}');
```

Comment: How can I store it to variable? Because I want to store it in Local Database.

Comment: The same way you can store any other data in a variable: `final variable = '...';`

Answer (score 0):

You Use Below Code :

```
DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
String date ="${today.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${today.month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}/${today.year.toString()}";
print(date);
```